# Image doesn't reflect automatically

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo.Upload for uploading image and temporrary view in IMG tag. It works great for chrome. But having issue in firefox and IE. In firefox, when i change src of IMG tag, i don't change image. In IE, I get filepath as filename from FILE, instead of FILENAME. Here is my

**html code:**

```
@Html.Kendo().Upload().Name("attachments").Async(async => async.Save("Save",
    "DashboardConfiguration").AutoUpload(true)).Multiple(false)
    .Events(e => e.Select("checksize").Success("onSuccess"))
    .HtmlAttributes(new { accept = ".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.bmp" })
<img alt="Captcha" src="@Url.Action("pdfImage")" id="imgicon" />
```

**javascript**

```
function onSuccess(e){
        $('#imgicon').attr('src','');
        $('#imgicon').attr('src','@Url.Action("pdfImage",
             "DashboardConfiguration")');
    }
```

**controller code:**

```
public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> attachments)
{
    byte[] image = null;
    // The Name of the Upload component is "attachments"
    foreach (var file in attachments)
    {
        string filePath = Server.MapPath(General.FaxFolder + "/" + file.FileName);
        file.SaveAs(filePath);

        // Some browsers send file names with full path. We only care about the file name.

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
            image = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
        }
        TempData["Image"] = image;
        System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
    }
    return Content("");
}

public ActionResult pdfImage()
{
    var icon = (byte[])TempData["Image"];
    return new FileStreamResult(new System.IO.MemoryStream(icon), "image/jpeg");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the browser to reload the image by passing an extra variable like so:

```
var d = new Date();
$('#imgicon').attr('src','');
$('#imgicon').attr('src','@Url.Action("pdfImage",
             "DashboardConfiguration")' + "?" + d.getTime());
```

Comment: Still it works for 90%. for 10% still keeping old copy unless refreshing page.